# Need workaround for SetEnabled(false) stopping e.processOnServer with DevExpress button

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress ASPxButton on a webpage of mine, and need a way to stop the user from being able to double click the button. My initial thought was to try:

```
    function OnClick(s, e) {
        s.SetEnabled(false);
        e.processOnServer;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I found out DevExpress stops all server side events from firing when you disable a button. So I went ahead and did some googling and ended up on the DevExpress website (which can be infuriatingly unhelpful sometimes)  which gave an official "work around" which they reference in the other help threads on their site regarding this issue. [Here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q184092) is the link for reference.

for anyone unwilling to click the link, they recommended this:

```
    var buttonClicked = false;
    function MyBtnClick(s,e){
        if(buttonClicked) return;
        buttonClicked = true;
        // do something
    }
```

which I turned into:

```
    var buttonClicked = false;
    function OnClick(s, e) {
        if (buttonClicked) return;
        buttonClicked = true;
        e.processOnServer;
    }
```

At first I thought this was working, but then realized it worked for a double click, but if the user were to click a third time, it just went ahead and processed again. For what should be an easy task, I seem to be having a hard time with this one (granted I am relatively new to JavaScript, so maybe the answer is obvious). If anyone knows of a way to disable the button after the first click while still allowing it to process on the server the first time, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing any operations on postback?

Comment: @psoshmo Isn't the answer below 'link only'. Should i vote for it to be deleted?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 yes probably

Answer (score 1):

I searched for some options for your issue, if you can check the links below :

> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q438771
>
> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q273711
>
> http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B132082

Comment: OK, so unfortunately none of these can really help me, although the third link was close (Im not using any update panels and do not want to change my aspx markup too much due to being VERY close to a release date). I appreciate the effort though.

Comment: Let me try to create the scenario of your case and send code to u. Thanks.

Comment: sure thing. Like I said, there are no update or callback panels. I just need it to disable after the first click (but I still need it to hit the server side event the first time). Thanks for all the effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is easy way how you can accomplish it.
On the click event you need to wrap the button table.

```
function SaveButtonClick(s,e) {
// Disable Save button in order not to click twice 
$("#" + s.uniqueID).wrap("<span style='pointer-even: none; opacity: 0.5;'> </span>");
if (ValidationSummary) {
      e.processOnServer = true;
}
else {
    e.processOnServer = false;
    // Enable Save button
    $("#" + s.uniqueID).unwrap();

  }
}
```

This is the easiest way I think.